# linq to EF, how to use 'top` method

Tags: c#, sql, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I want to use linq to Entities to bring the `top` record ordered by descending column `Value1`.

I know I ca write like:

MyCollection.OrderByDescending(item => item.Value1).FirstOrDefault();

But how do I use the folloing method `Top` ?

System.Data.Objects.ObjectQuery.Top(string, params System.Data.Objects.ObjectParameter[])

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/bb300906.aspx

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: This answer was written when the question was *specifically* about LINQ to SQL.

`System.Data.Objects` is used for Entity Framework rather than LINQ to SQL as far as I can tell - but to find the top N values in either LINQ to SQL or even LINQ to Objects, you'd usually just use `Take`:

```
var query = db.Customers
              .OrderByDescending(c => c.Value1)
              .Take(10);
```

(I'd *really* encourage you to try to use more meaningful names than `Value1` though...)

EDIT: Even in Entity Framework, I'd usually use `Take` in LINQ queries - it's "the LINQ way" of representing the first N results. If you really, really want to use `Top`, the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb155995.aspx) provides examples - but you should consider *why* you want to use `Top` rather than `Take`. (You've given us no context to work with.)

Comment: My bad, I meant linq to  Entities. I know this syntax. I asked specifically about `top` syntax. I have found the answer: `Top(1, new ObjectParameter("@CtidProdId")).Select(item => item.CtidProdId).SingleOrDefault()`

Comment: @EladBenda: What Jon showed you is the LINQ equivalent of SQL's `top`.

Comment: @EladBenda: You specifically asked about LINQ to SQL, then you changed your question. You also said you knew about `FirstOrDefault`, which isn't the same as knowing about `Take`. If you're going to ask the wrong question, you should expect to get answers which don't cover what you want. To be honest I'd use `Take` even in Entity Framework unless you actually *need* to use `Top`. It really doesn't help when your question is vague.

Answer (score 1):

Please look at MSDN for an example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/bb155995.aspx

```
using (AdventureWorksEntities context =
    new AdventureWorksEntities())
{
    string queryString =
        @"SELECT VALUE product FROM AdventureWorksEntities.Products AS product";

    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery1 =
        new ObjectQuery<Product>(queryString, context, MergeOption.NoTracking);

    ObjectQuery<Product> productQuery2 = productQuery1.Top("2");

    // Iterate through the collection of Product items. 
    foreach (Product result in productQuery2)
        Console.WriteLine("{0}", result.Name);
}
```

Or if you just have a `List<T>` consider using the `Take()` extension.

```
List<string> strs = new List<strs>() { "1", "2", "3", "4" };
var firstTwo = strs.Take(2);
```